# using ifelse with Dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have a vector of dates and I want to set the date to NA if it is prior to another vector.

I tried `ifelse(date_vector1>=date_vector2, date_vector1, NA)`, but the output is not a Date and applying `as.Date()` return an error.

I then tried `dplyr::if_else(date_vector1>=date_vector2, date_vector1, NA_real_)`, but it returns the same error.

The error is this one :

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

How can I use the `ifelse` statement with dates ?

Comment: Please don't use `if_else` or `ifelse` on dates.  Instead try `setDT(df1)[date_vector>= date_vector2,  newcol := date_vector1]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` to create a new column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[date_vector1>= date_vector2, newcol := date_vector1]
df1
#   date_vector1 date_vector2     newcol
#1:   2017-05-29   2017-05-13 2017-05-29  
#2:   2017-05-22   2017-05-26       <NA>
#3:   2017-05-26   2017-05-18 2017-05-26
#4:   2017-05-28   2017-05-14 2017-05-28
#5:   2017-05-25   2017-05-27       <NA>
```

If both these are vectors are not a variable in a data.frame/data.table, then do

```
i1 <- date_vector1>= date_vector2
newvector <- date_vector2
newvector[i1] <- date_vector1[i1]
newvector[!i1] <- NA
newvector
#[1] "2017-05-29" NA           "2017-05-26" "2017-05-28" NA
```

---

It is better not to use `ifelse` on `Date` as dates are stored as integers it will coerce to `integer` class and we may have to convert it back to `Date` class again with `as.Date(..., origin = '1970-01-01')`

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
date_vector1 <- sample((Sys.Date() - 1:10), 5, replace = FALSE)
date_vector2 <- sample((Sys.Date() - 1:20), 5, replace = FALSE)
df1 <- data.frame(date_vector1, date_vector2)
```

Comment: I finally went for `foo=date_vector1` and `foo[date_vector1>= date_vector2]=NA`, but your answer may be very valuable for other cases

Answer (score 1):

This because [`ifelse` strips the class attribute](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse). You can restore it with e.g.

```
date_vector3 <- ifelse(date_vector1>=date_vector2, date_vector1, NA)
class(date_vector3) <- "Date"
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally go for `replace()` when one of the cases is a fixed value:

```r
date1 <- Sys.Date() + c(-1, 0, 1)
date2 <- Sys.Date() + c(0, 0, 0)

replace(date1, which(date1 < date2), NA)
#> [1] NA           "2022-02-25" "2022-02-26"
```